# How to separate out internal and external API Swagger documentation in .Net Core project

Tags: swagger, umbraco, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a .Net Core project (using Umbraco) which exposes some public-facing API endpoints and has some internal organisation-facing API endpoints. I am using Swagger (through `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`) to generate documentation and I have split the documents into two parts like this:

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc("public", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Title = "Public Facing API",
            Version = "v1",
        });
        options.SwaggerDoc("internal", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Title = "Internal API",
            Version = "v1",
        });
   }
```

Followed by:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SwaggerBuilderExtensions.UseSwagger(app); // this is necessary for Swashbuckle under Umbraco!
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SupportedSubmitMethods(new SubmitMethod[] { SubmitMethod.Get, SubmitMethod.Head });
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/public/swagger.json", "Public Facing API");
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/internal/swagger.json", " Internal API");

    });
```

My API documentation is generated this way, but I don't want the internal API signatures to be available to everyone. Ideally I would like to be able to limit access to the Internal endpoint to authenticated users.

I tried using a middleware approach to close off the `swagger\internal\swagger.json` endpont, but that didn't work with a static file and I don't know whether limiting access to that json file at runtime would impact how it works in general.

I would be happy to create a single document but limit what options it shows based on the user making the request, to create entirely different `/swagger/internal/index.html` and `/swagger/external/index.html` files, or to wrap the Swagger index document into CMS view partial. What is the best way to achieve this?